# Ruby equivalent to php_sapi_name

Tags: php, ruby

What is the Ruby convention for determining whether you are running in CLI (like php_sapi_name function in PHP) vs. processing an HTTP request?

I was thinking I could test if request is defined, or some other inferential method, but there must be a convention I should follow.

Comment: What do you define as a CLI? Just IRB? What about HTTP request—do you only care about Rack?

Comment: That's an excellent clarification question. I have background ActiveRecord/Rails based "batch" jobs that are not User-centric (do not require a user context), but still run in a Railsy manner. They are NOT IRB. In truth if it is not a Web-triggered request - I would like to use that as the binary determination. In the future they may also be initiated as Rake jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standardized method here since Ruby is a scripting language that may or may not be embedded in a web-server process. It may be running as a disconnected background process as well, though one that's not necessarily web-facing.

In the HTTP environment you generally have variables defined like `ENV['SERVER_NAME']` and others from the [CGI specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). These would not be present in command-line environments.

Generally it's better to test if you're running within Rack or Rails or whatever particular web framework is being employed to interface with the HTTP layer. For instance, `defined?(Rails)` will indicate if Rails is loaded, though this will also be true for `rake` tasks and `rails console` type usage.